# Where can I find System.TeamProjectId for a project in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I need this Id upfront but I can't seem to find it anywhere online?
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts) only refers to it as a system variable.

**Context:**
I have multiple projects and I want to identify a project during CI so it can run a powershell script hosted in another repository.

Comment: Do you need the Id durind the build? if so, read the system variable (it's environment variable).

Comment: I want it in advance so I can use it to bootstrap powershell scripts specific for a project.

Comment: it's madness that even in 2021 it's necessary to either call an API endpoint or inspect the HTML just to get the ID of a project in devops, especially when there are pipeline tasks that need it </rant>

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can get the all team projects id with [REST Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0):

```
 https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.0-preview.3
```

Results:

```
 {
  "count": 3,
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1",
      "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-TFVC",
      "description": "Team Foundation Version Control projects.",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/eb6e4656-77fc-42a1-9181-4c6d8e9da5d1",
      "state": "wellFormed"
    },
    {
      "id": "6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
      "name": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git",
      "description": "Git projects",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c",
      "state": "wellFormed"
    },
    {
      "id": "281f9a5b-af0d-49b4-a1df-fe6f5e5f84d0",
      "name": "TestGit",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/projects/281f9a5b-af0d-49b4-a1df-fe6f5e5f84d0",
      "state": "wellFormed"
    }
  ]
}
```

You don't even need use Postman or create Http request, just enter the API url above in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to find it on the Azure Devops organization page but this is the second best option.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I do not think this information is available without the api.

Comment: Hi Shayki, I tried above but getting 302 error. "Object Moved". Though it worked fine in past.

Comment: @Maddy I tried it now and it works for me. did you use Azure DevOps Server maybe?

Comment: All good found the solution. The PAT we are getting back was decoded one and Azure DevOps API needs the encoded one. I then generated the PAT and encoded it and used in Postman and it worked

Comment: I get Azure DevOps Services | Sign In in my postman when I raise the request. Can you please tell where to get a token and where to put it in the request to sign in?

Comment: @E.Erfan see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71068040/azure-devops-api-authentication

Answer (score 21):

You can examine the HTML in the UI of the dashboard on your organisation projects page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As outlined here on [azure deops documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/work-with-urls?view=azure-devops&tabs=http#with-the-organizations-name), you can `curl` below url:

```bash
curl "https://dev.azure.com/_apis/resourceAreas/79134C72-4A58-4B42-976C-04E7115F32BF?accountName=<ORG_NAME_HERE>&api-version=5.0-preview.1"

# Output: 
{"id":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","name":"core","locationUrl":"https://dev.azure.com/ORG_NAME_HERE/"}
```

> With just the organization's name or ID, you can get its base URL using the global Resource Areas REST API (https://dev.azure.com/_apis/resourceAreas). This API doesn't require authentication. It also provides information about the location (URL) of the organization and the base URL for REST APIs, which can live on different domains.