# Azure DevOps API Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-ad-msal

I would like to use the Azure DevOps API to create a PAT for my user. But I'm unable to authenticate yet. In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) document from Microsoft, they state that authentication is possible with a PAT, but it is not true. I'm getting a HTTP 203 with a Sign In page in response.

PS: I'm using Postman to test the API requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [security section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#accesstoken) of this REST API is misleading.

In fact, this REST API cannot be authenticated with PAT, as mentioned in [another document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops):

> To use the API, you must authenticate with an Azure AD token.

> Unlike other Azure DevOps Services APIs, **users must provide an Azure AD access token to use this API instead of a PAT token**. Azure AD tokens are a safer authentication mechanism than using PATs. Given this API’s ability to create and revoke PATs, we want to ensure that such powerful functionality is given to allowed users only.

This document also explains how to use this REST API in detail, which you can refer to.

Comment: I got a bearer token through an App Registration and calling "login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token. But this bearer token also does not work...

Comment: @plsfix I still have the same issue, I got the bearer token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/v2.0/token and that token is not working in PAT API endpoint.

Comment: @plsfix However what I did for now is, I used the python flask application provided by microsoft here https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/PersonalAccessTokenAPIAppSample and I retrieved the bearer token from the API logs and it worked fine for me. But I am still trying to figure out the way for getting the Azure AD Access token thing.

Comment: @Saad I'm on a call with a Microsoft developer tomorrow. Will let you know the results.

Comment: @plsfix Heyyy, Thanks ! If you could just let me know about the results also. It would be really awesome.

Comment: @Saad the library for flask seems to be the easiest solution. We ditched our project and decided to grab a PAT manually via the GUI.

Comment: I am confused, I authenticate to the AZ Devops API with a PAT just fine, you are saying it's not possible?

Comment: @Rakim original poster's question is about [Pats - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokens/pats/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) API. REST APIs **about tokens** are special and only can use Azure AD token (now Microsoft Entra token) for authentification. Other REST APIs, like listing work items, can use PAT definitely.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it does work, you're just not setting it up right.

Look at the Basic Authentication of [this document](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#basic-auth). You need to base 64 encode the username password like this: `username:PAT`. Spearate the two with the colon.

Comment: This worked! I used by email address for the username part

Comment: Thanks! I used the `requests` library in Python and I think I didn't need my username, just by PAT: `requests.get(diff_url, auth=('', personal_access_token))`

Comment: Does this work with the system access token in a pipeline?

Comment: I don't see why running it in a pipeline versus say Postman would make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when sending a request with headers like so

`'Authentication': 'Basic <Base-64 encoded PAT>'`

You have to include `':'` at the beginning of your PAT before you encode it (use Base-64 with padding).
Use a colon even if you do not include username.

P.S I think in Postman you don't need to encode your PAT.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share how I successfully connected to the Azure DevOps API using a Personal Access Token (PAT) from a PowerShell script. While this might be a bit late, I hope it helps others who come across this.

First, you'll need to have a PAT created in your Azure DevOps account

Now, here's the PowerShell script :`

## Define your Personal Access Token (PAT)

$pat = "YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"

## Define the DevOps API URL

$jsonUrl = "YOUR_JSON_URL_HERE"

## Create headers with the PAT for authentication

$headers = @{
Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
}

## Make the request with authentication headers

$jsonContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $jsonUrl -Headers $headers

`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, no need to base64 encode anything:

[image]