# Cannot update variable group with Azure DevOps API _apis/distributedtask/variablegroups

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to update a variable group from an Azure DevOps Pipeline.  This is the [API documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).  I am calling this API via Postman with HTTP PUT and a Header Authorization Basic {PAT}. The URL is [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=6.0-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/%7BgroupId%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.2)  Regardless of the JSON body it always returns:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "Project information name is not valid for variable group.",
  "typeName": "System.ArgumentException, mscorlib",
  "typeKey": "ArgumentException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 0
 }
```

Sample JSON Bodies:

Test 1

```
{
  "type": "Vsts",
  "name":"JobStatus"
}
```

Test 2

```
{
  "variables": {
      "rest-var1": {
          "isSecret": false,
          "value": "rest-var-value-1"
      },
      "rest-var2": {
          "isSecret": false,
          "value": "rest-var-value-2"
      },
      "rest-var3": {
          "isSecret": false,
          "value": "rest-var-value-3"
      }
  },
  "name":"JobStatus"
}
```

If I call this same API with HTTP GET it returns all of the details of the group.  This was reported as a bug to Microsoft but [the page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/api-version60-preview2-throws-project-information/1165675) didn't provide any details as to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Project information name is not valid for variable group."

The error means that you need to define the project information in the Request Body.

Here is the Rest API example:

Rest API url:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "name":"{variablegroupname}",

    "type":"Vsts",
    "variables":{
        "var1":{
            "isSecret":false,
            "value": "xx"
            },
        "var2":{
            "isSecret":false,
            "value": "xx"
            },
        "var3":{
            "isSecret":false,
            "value": "xx"
            }
        },
        "variableGroupProjectReferences":[
            {
                "name":"{variablegroupname}",
                "projectReference":
                    {
                        "id":"{projectid}"  
                    }
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.  To find the {projectid} which is mentioned in this answer you can use this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866107/where-can-i-find-system-teamprojectid-for-a-project-in-azure-devops.  The first answer did not work for me but with the 2nd answer I was able to find the correct projectid.

Comment: So this works for me, thank you. One question: I noticed that if the group starts with several variables and I only specify one variable to update, it wipes all the other variables out. Is there a way to update a variable without wiping out the others in the group?

Comment: My variableGroupProjectReferences is null when i GET. I tries to put as it is (null) on [] I mean @() and always i get:
`Invoke-RestMethod: {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Project information name is not
valid for variable group.","typeName":"System.ArgumentException,
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}`